# Selected option value in <select> does not $_POST with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using two dropdowns. One of them (the second one) uses AJAX for selecting data from the database and displaying partial records on the page. I was able to post other input text(machine_no) but not the selected values in dropdowns.

HTML part

```
<form action="page.php" name="form" method="post">
   <select name="material_type" form="form" required>
         <option disabled selected>(Select Type)</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <select name="part_no" id="part_no" form="form" required>
         <option disabled selected>(Select Part)</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  <div class="lot-no-list" id="lot-no-list"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
       <input type="text" name="machine_no" id="machine_no" maxlength="15" required>
  </div>
 </form>
```

jQuery + AJAX part

```
$('#part_no').change(function (event) 
{
      var option = this.value;

  if (option == '') 
  {
       $("#group4").hide();    

  }else
  {
      $("#group4").show();

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                /*$('lot-no-list').html(xmlhttp.responseText);*/
                document.getElementById("lot-no-list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log(option);
             }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","get_assignments.php?rec="+option,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

  }
});
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking, but if you are trying to have the ajax run when you select either dropdown, you need to trigger the event using a class or type. If you are saying it's not sending all the data from the form, then likely because you are just sending one value in your query string(`"get_assignments.php?rec="+option`)...but not sure exactly what you are saying.

Comment: What you mean by _I was able to post other input values_. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wasn't able to post the selected value to the next page. I have no problem in displaying the ajax part. I have other input text included in form and wasn't included on my original post.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery.ajax() API instead of XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to post the value changing the jquery part

from

```
var option = this.value;
```

to

```
var option = $(this).children(':selected').val();
```

The answer was previously posted and it worked.